# Registering taxonomy for custom post type in "functionality plugin" causes error 500

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm moving functionality from a theme's functions.php to a "functionality plugin". For some reason, when in functions.php, everything works perfectly fine. But when I move it into plugin, I get error 500 for the entire wp-admin area.

I was able to pinpoint problem to taxonomy registration block of code by excluding functionality blocks piece by piece.

Here is the whole custom post type registration code:

```
function create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'Ads',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name'               => 'Ads',
        'singular_name'      => 'Ad',
        'menu_name'          => 'Ads',
        'name_admin_bar'     => 'Ad',
        'add_new'            => 'Add New',
        'add_new_item'       => 'Add New Ad',
        'new_item'           => 'New Ad',
        'edit_item'          => 'Edit Ad',
        'view_item'          => 'View Ad',
        'all_items'          => 'All Ads',
        'search_items'       => 'Search Ads',
        'parent_item_colon'  => 'Parent Ads:',
        'not_found'          => 'No ads found.',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No ads found in Trash.'
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'rewrite' => true,
      'hierarchical' => true,
      'supports' => array( 
        'title', 
        'revisions'
    ),
    )
  );
}
/* This piece bellow is causing trouble*/
register_taxonomy("Placements", array("ads"), array(
    "hierarchical" => true,
    "label" => "Placements",
    "singular_label" => "Placement",
    "rewrite" => true
));
/* End of trouble making code */
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
```

and here is the error log

> [Tue May 01 23:11:04.268105 2018] [:error] [pid 24511] [client 174.214.1.78:15113] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function add_rewrite_tag() on null in /nas/content/live/adsplugintest/wp-includes/rewrite.php:172\nStack trace:\n#0 /nas/content/live/adsplugintest/wp-includes/class-wp-taxonomy.php(379): add_rewrite_tag('%Placements%', '([^/]+)', 'placements=')\n#1 /nas/content/live/adsplugintest/wp-includes/taxonomy.php(386): WP_Taxonomy->add_rewrite_rules()\n#2 /nas/content/live/adsplugintest/wp-content/plugins/custom-ads-plugin/custom-ads.php(45): register_taxonomy('Placements', Array, Array)\n#3 /nas/content/live/adsplugintest/wp-settings.php(305): include_once('/nas/content/li...')\n#4 /nas/content/live/adsplugintest/wp-config.php(121): require_once('/nas/content/li...')\n#5 /nas/content/live/adsplugintest/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/nas/content/li...')\n#6 /nas/content/live/adsplugintest/wp-admin/admin.php(31): require_once('/nas/content/li...')\n#7 /nas/content/live/adsplugintest/wp-admin/index.php(10): require_once('/nas/content/li...')\n#8 {main}\n thrown in /nas/content/live/adsplugintest/wp-includes/rewrite.php on line 172

Comment: [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) is a generic server-side error message. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail. Without that we can't help you.

Comment: added the error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the `register_taxonomy()` method as part of the `init` action (as you've done for `register_post_type()`.

Updated code would be:

```
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( ... );
    register_taxonomy( ... );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
```

At the moment, you're calling `register_taxonomy()` directly instead of via the `init` action, so it's firing too soon for WordPress to handle it appropriately.

The WordPress Codex for [`register_taxonomy()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) also mentions this:

> **Use the `init` action to call this function.** Calling it outside of an action can lead to troubles. See [#15568](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15568) for details.

Comment: works great! Thanks. A follow up question, if you don't mind. Do you know why it worked in functions.php and didn't in the plugin?

Comment: @kulbulbul I could dig through the WordPress code to find the exact reason, but it would simply be the order in which different files/functions are loaded and executed. Plugins would be processed before theme files are, so the plugin is firing before WordPress has ran the functions required to be ready to register additional taxonomies. By Adding the function to the `init` action, WordPress can queue the required functions to be run at the required time, once everything is ready.